# Row level string comparison in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to compare two csv file at row level. If string is matched then print the correct string.

```
import csv
file1 = open('/a1.csv','rb')
file2 = open('/test.csv','rb')
myfile = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')
myfile1 = csv.reader(file2, delimiter=',')
    for row in myfile:
        for row1 in myfile1:
            new=""
            if row1[0] == row:
                new = row[0]
            else:
                new = row1[0]
            print new
```

a1.csv contain sample input as:

```
A,a,a1,a2
B,b,b1,b5
```

test.csv contain sample input as:

```
a
a!
```

If string is matched, for example "a" == "A,a,a1,a2" then I want to print 'A' and In case there is no match, for example "a!" == "A,a,a1,a2" then need to print 'a!'

My code is printing "a" and "a!" output without comparison. Is this the incorrect way to compare a string?

Comment: you want to check `line1` of `test.csv` against all lines of `a1.csv` or just want to compare `line1` of `test.csv` to `line1` of `a1.csv` ?

Comment: I want to compare line1 of test.csv against all lines of a1.csv, and same line2 of test.csv against all lines of a1.csv

Comment: @Manish in your first if condition the index for row[] is missing. Could that be an issue ?

Comment: @Pradeep sorry by mistake I kept row[ ] in code, I was getting the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this (note the in statement instead of '==') also note that the printing logic has changed:

```
import csv
file1 = open('/a1.csv','rb')
file2 = open('/test.csv','rb')
a1 = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')
test = csv.reader(file2, delimiter=',')


for row1 in test:
    new=""
    found = False
    for row in a1:
        if row1[0] in row:
            new = row[0]
            found = True
    if not found:
        new = row1[0]
    print new
    file1.seek(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But its matching from only 1 row, for example I input "a", "b" in test.csv as line seperated format. I got output as "A", "b" instead of "A", "B"

Comment: I forgot to set the test.csv back to the start, hence it didn't re-enter the for loop. PLease see the corrected version.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but now it gives all combination output such as 'A', 'b' .... 'a', 'B' ...'a','b'

Comment: @ManishV you said that you want to test line 1 of test.csv against all lines of a1. So if there are 2 rows in each file you should get 4 out puts right? 
i.e. a => A,a,a1,a2 = 'A'
b => A,a,a1,a2 = 'b'
a => B,b,b1,b5 = 'a'
b => B,b,b1,b5 = 'B'

Comment: I want to test against all the lines. For input "a", "b"; expected output is "A", "B", i.e a => A,a,a1,a2 = 'A'; b => B,b,b1,b5 = 'B'. If input doesn't match then input should be same and if matched then its replaced. Is it possible without generating repeative output? Thank you

Comment: @ManishV Just to be clear. If you wanted to test against all of the lines you should expect 4 outputs:
test.csv line1 => a1.csv line1
test.csv line1 => a1.csv line2
test.csv line2 => a1.csv line1
test.csv line2 => a1.csv line2

When should an output not be produced?

Comment: Sorry for the mis-understanding, output should not be produce if there is no match. For example, input "a", "b" , "a!" expected output "A" (match), "B"(match), "a!" (no match).

Comment: I am still a little confused. You said that "output should not be produced if there is no match", but then in your example the expected output is "a!" when there is no match.... I have updated my solution to not output if there is no match, is this what you want?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I mean to say if there is no match then output is same as input.. Thanks for help

Comment: Ok. So when a1.csv is as per your original post and test.csv is "a" <newline> "b". Then you would expect the following output: A, b, a, B is that right?

Comment: Input: "a" <newline> "b" Output : "A" <newline> "B". Sorry for the inconvenience. Another example, input: "a", "a!", "b" output: "A" , "a!", "B. As "a" and "b" match, so values are updated and if there is no match output is same as input

Comment: @ManishV. Ok hopefully I now have the right end of the stick. I just needed to tweak the print logic. Let me know what you think.

Comment: No probs. If it does what you want, please can you mark it as answered? Thanks